# Bash compute the letter suffix from the split command (i.e. integer into base 26 with letters)

Tags: bash, radix, filesplitting

The `split` command produces by default a file suffix of the form "aa" "ab" ... "by" "bz"...

However in a script, I need to recover this suffix, starting from the file number as an integer (without globbing).

I wrote the following code, but maybe bash wizards here have ***a more concise solution***?

```sh
alph="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for j in {0..100}; do
    # Convert j to the split suffix (aa ab ac ...)
    first=$(( j / 26 ))    
    sec=$(( j % 26 ))
    echo "${alph:$first:1}${alph:$sec:1}"
done
```

Alternatively, I could use `bc` with the `obase` variable, but it only outputs one number in case j<26.

```
bc <<< 'obase=26; 5'
# 05
bc <<< 'obase=26; 31'
# 01 05
```

Comment: What about using `split --numeric-suffixes`? Then it's just `$j`. Your solution looks quite nice!

Comment: Do you _want to_ generate first 100 suffixes or this is just an example and you just want concise way of converting the number to suffix?

Comment: Yes, this may simplify downstream work, but there are other advantages with default split: faster to write/read, more compact file names. Also with `--numeric-suffixes`/`-d`, one still needs to preprocess the integer to add the padding zeroes, with `printf -v padded_j '%03d' "$j"`.

Comment: @KamilCuk In my use case, I do want to generate the full list.

Comment: Then I think your solution is really fine. You could do it in awk, maybe will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From top of my head, depending on `97` beeing ASCII `a`:

```
printf "\x$(printf %x $((97+j/26)))\x$(printf %x $((97+j%26)))\n"
printf "\\$(printf %o $((97+j/26)))\\$(printf %o $((97+j%26)))\n"
awk "BEGIN{ printf \"%c%c\\n\", $((97+j/26)), $((97+j%26))}" <&-
printf %x $((97+j/26)) $((97+j%26)) | xxd -r -p
```

You could also just write without temporary variables:

```
echo "${alph:j/26:1}${alph:j%26:1}"
```

> In my use case, I do want to generate the full list

`awk` should be fast:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=0;i<=100;++i) printf "%c%c\n", 97+i/26, 97+i%26}' <&-
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possibility to use arithmetics inside parameter expansion! and the '%c' formatting using Awk.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner and specify the file numbers (0-indexed) as arguments, for example:

```
perl -le 'print for ("aa".."zz")[@ARGV]' 0 25 26
```

Output:

```
aa
az
ba
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`@ARGV` : array of the command-line arguments.

Comment: Wow, the neatest trick is that Perl understands how to increment from "aa" to "zz".